# How to replace specific characters within a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Given a string like `aaabba`, I want a function which turns the **a's** to **b's** and the **b's** to **a's**, returning `bbbaab`.

I tried this clumsy one:

```
var newa = [];
function swit(x) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] === 'a') {
            newa.push('b');
        } 
        else if (x[i] === 'b') {
            newa.push('a');
        } 
        alert(newa);
    }
}
swit("aaab");
```

After clicking through a lot of alerts, finally, the last alert shows the intended result. But I want it without commas and at the first place – not after many iterations:

[image]

I also tried the `string.replace()` Method – in combination with a `for`-loop:

```
function swit(x) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] === 'a') {
            x.replace('a', 'b');
        } 
        else if (x[i] === 'b') {
            x.replace('b', 'a');
        } 
        alert(x);
    }
}
swit("aaab");
```

**But nothing changes. Why?**

Could you please give me a hint of what went wrong and how to get the desired result?

Comment: Well when you do an alert with an array it uses toString() which has commas....

Comment: Have you though about using regular expressions? You can either use `myString.replace(/somePattern/g, 'replaceTo')` or with use of `new RegExp(options)`. Playground here: https://regexr.com/, my quick (may not work the way you want it to but you get the idea) example here: https://jsfiddle.net/b1hgtnfy/11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your alert line out of the for loop to the end, and use **[Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** to convert `newa` into a string without commas.

Also, it would make sense to move the `newa` array declaration inside the `swit` function.

Lastly, you should consider also adding an else condition where you just push the exact same current character onto the `newa` array if it is not an `a` or `b`, so the output string length is the same as the original string.

```js
function swit(x) { 
  var newa = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] === 'a') {
      newa.push('b');
    } else if (x[i] === 'b') {
      newa.push('a');
    } else {
      newa.push(x[i])
    }
  }
  alert(newa.join(""));
}

swit("aaab");
swit("aasdfcvbab");
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to split text to single characters using `split`, then map array of chars by simply replace `a => b` and `b => a` and `join` it together again, or just use `replace`

```
'bbbaab'.split('').map(char => char === 'a' ? 'b' : 'a').join('');

'bbbaab'.replace(/a|b/g, (match) => match === 'a' ? 'b' : 'a');
```

```js
function swap(str) {
  return str.split('').map(char => char === 'a' ? 'b' : 'a').join('');
}
function swap2(str) {
  return str.replace(/a|b/g, (match) => match === 'a' ? 'b' : 'a');
}

console.log(swap('bbbaab'));
console.log(swap2('bbbaab'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "aaab";
str = str.replace(/a|b/g, v => {
       if(v=="a"){
         return "b"
       }else{
         return "a"
       }
    });

console.log(str);
```

Comment: You can eliminate the if/else tree (especially once you start adding more replacement rules) with a hash map:

`"aaabba".replace(/a|b/g, x => { const map = { a: 'b', b: 'a' }; return map[x]; })`

Answer (score 0):

Your first example works but replaces a string with an array of characters (which is different from a string). You can simply `join` the resulting array to get desired result:

```
function swit(x) {
    var newa = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] === 'a') {
            newa.push('b');
        } else if (x[i] === 'b') {
            newa.push('a');
        }
    }

    var arrayJoined = newa.join('');
    alert(arrayJoined);
    return arrayJoined;
}
```

For your second example, `replace` replaces all occurences in a string and does not need to be run in a for loop. So what you actually do in your second code sample is: `for each character in string: if character is 'a', replace by b. if character is 'b', replace by a`. Which basically just switches all `a`'s to `b`'s and `b`'s back to `a`'s. Which results in the same output string as your input string.